# Wiring up modern ceiling rose in old house

Tags: lighting

I am in the process of replacing an old light fitting, however I'm stuck because the old fitting has a completely different circuit to the new one.

From basic research, I believe the new ceiling rose is on a loop system. The old one simply had a single junction box with the live, earth, and neutral wires going in. (Pictures linked below).

My question is, how do I wire up the new ceiling rose? I've looked at the diagrams of the loop circuits and they seem to have lots more wires involved than I appear to have coming out the ceiling.

If it is possible to get this wired up properly, I'd really appreciate some simple instructions of which wires to put where!

I will link to pictures (apologies I cannot upload multiple on here) of how the old light was wired, what wires are coming out the ceiling, and what the new circuit looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FlNF.jpg

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the first and last images ie old rose and new rose, then:

1) the red wire goes to the brown on the new rose,

2) the two black ones to the blue wire on the new rose and

3( the green or earth or ground wires go to the brass terminal on the new rose.

You don't have anything to use "loop", which would be for feeding the "next" light.

Comment: That's exactly how I had it the first time around and it didn't come on. I'm gonna try once more, maybe the wires weren't all making contact properly? I have no way to test the bulb because I haven't got any other bayonet fittings, so I don't even know if the bulb is okay! Although its brand new so should be fine

Comment: Well, it is highly likely that you have an internal break in one of the wires - old wires “work harden” and break when you start moving them. Have you checked the lamp fitting? New ones need to be checked - screws notvtight rtc.

Comment: Update: I feel like an idiot. Just wired it all up again and it still didn't work, but we found another bulb... The other bulb works fine! So I think we bought a dud -.-